# how to make toggle side bar using vue js with vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to create sidebar with toggle option.If i click icon sidebar should be visible left side of the page and the icon should be next sidebar. if i click icon again sidebar should be hide.Using vue js and vuetify

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

You should start by reading through the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/getting-started/quick-start) for Vuetify.

The documentation provide an example of this under [Pre-made Layouts](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/pre-made-layouts).

Baseline layout with Navigation Drawer: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/baseline

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer

Comment: Since you are new here i'am also adding this for you to read. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Happy coding!